# working on relation many to many in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

i made third table because i need extra colums in third table. 
i has written relation method in both model but id is not 
moving
in user model  method is

```
   class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_type_id', 'accountType', 'email', 'password',  'userName', 'gender', 'dob', 'country', 'city', 'mobileNo', 'cnic', 'address',
        'degreeLevel', 'degreeTitle', 'institution', 'complitionYear', 'acedCountry', 'experience', 'workExperience', 'industry', 'perCountry', 'cv'

    ];

    protected $table = 'users';

    /********************************************************************/
    /*     Relationship between User and Ranklist     */
    /*******************************************************************/

    public function RankList()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RankList','user_id');

    }


    public function Company()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Company');

    }



    public function newsAndEvents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\newsAndEvents','user_id');

    }
    /********************************************************************/
    /*     Relationship between User and user type     */
    /*******************************************************************/


    public function UserType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserType','user_type_id');

    }
    public function course_outline()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CourseOuline','user_id');

    }
    public function Jobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job','Job_User','User_id','Job_id');
    }


    public function Skill_User()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Skill','Skill_User','Skill_id','User_id');
    }

    public function Feedback_User()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Feedback','Feedback_User','Feedback_id','User_id');
    }
}
    in job model method is


     class Job extends Model
{

   use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    /**************************************************/
    /*            Company Post Job                    */
    /**************************************************/

    protected $fillable = [
        'jobType', 'jobTitle','skills','industry', 'department', 'vacancy', 'qualification', 'degreeTitle', 'miniExperience', 'jobCategory',
        'city', 'gender', 'companyName', 'description','posting_date', 'applied_date', 'companyLogo',

    ];

    protected $table = 'jobs';

    /**************************************************/
    /*     Relationships between company and job      */
    /**************************************************/

    public function Company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company','company_id');

    }
    public function job_skill()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Skill','Job_Skill','Job_id','skill_id');
    }
    public function Users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','Job_User','User_id','Job_id');
    }

}
pivot table code  is

    class Job_User extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
          'cv','current_salary','expected_salary','status',
        ];
        protected $table = 'jobs_users';
    }
```

but user apply on job error is shown
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bridging_the_gap`.`jobs_users`, CONSTRAINT `jobs_users_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `jobs_users` (`cv`, `current_salary`, `expected_salary`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1st, 15,000-19,999, 30,000-39,999, 2016-06-02 10:57:02, 2016-06-02 10:57:02))

Comment: Where is model of your pivot table? Can you provide that code? If you don't have pivot table then check [this](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/) first.

Comment: i have not written any method in pivot table but i have pivot table. kindly tell me the method

Comment: Check link in my first comment first. Then if got more problems ask.

Comment: i have written methods according to the given link but error is same

Comment: Do you have 2 models of 3 (including pivot model)? If got 3 models, then add code of pivot to the question

Comment: i have added code of pivot table in question but i have written any belongsToMany method in pivot table . please tell if i need to add any method in pivot table

Comment: Can u provide full code of both models (users and jobs)?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
//model jobs
public function Jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\jobs_users');    
}

//model users
public function Users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\jobs_users');  
}

//model pivot - jobs_users
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\user');
}

public function jobs() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\job');
}
```

This are basics to make pivot (many to many relation). For more fields you have to define in pivot model extra fields etc...

Hope it helps

Comment: I have written same code as asked to try but error is same till now

Comment: Do you have that pivot table in database? with same column id's like in User and Job models?

Comment: in pivot table there are two colums $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();

Comment: Add those columns into fillable model `jobs_users` and that should do it

Comment: i should add jobs method in job model or users method in job model??? kindly clear this confusion

Comment: jobs_users is last 2 methods, users and jobs have only 1 method